# Start an animation when the other one is finished/completed in jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, callback

This is not working for me:

```
$(".button").click(function(){ 
    $("#start").animate({
        "opacity": ".3"
    }, "slow", function(){
        $("#start").animate({"height": "0"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

I want a `div` to animate and when it's done, animate again.

Doesn't matter what I search on Google... on all the blogs and forums it says that this should be the only way to do it.

Comment: So what is wrong with what you found on Google (posted above) and what exactly is the question then?

Comment: Actually, as both animations run on the same element (`#start`), and so in the same animation queue, there is no need to start the second animation in the oncomplete-callback function of the first. Simply: `$('#start').animate(...).animate(...)` would do the same thing.

Comment: You could use [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to add a pause before starting the second animation rather than sticking it in the callback, but to be honest I'm with @Sparky672 here... **Edit:** Or do what Yoshi says; that's better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we'll need to see your html. Works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/LTHtb/

```
<div class="button">start</div>

<div id="start"></div>

<script>
$(".button").click(function(){ 
$("#start").animate({
"opacity": ".3"
}, "slow", function(){
$("#start").animate({"height": "0"}, "fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
 #start{
 height:200px;
  width:200px;
  margin-top:20px; 
  background-color:#e1e1e1;
}

.button{
   padding:10px;
   background-color:#369; 
   cursor: pointer;
   width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Asking for HTML and telling him that his code is working is not an answer to anything.

Comment: His jQuery *does* work. There is a good chance that he is using an ID or class in reverse. I also included a fiddle for him to look at for troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, helpful maybe.  But it's still **not** an _answer_ to his question.  Answer section is only for answers to questions, not helpful comments.

Comment: Im sorry indeed it works. I was just so angry because nothing worked. But it was my own fault. My file was all messy and now i cleaned it up and it just works fine. 

Thanks you Grillz for showing me that it works because i would have tried something diffrent that probably doesnt work.

Comment: @Sparky672 I'm sorry, but I disagree. This code answers his question: "I want a div to animate and when it's done, animate again."

Comment: @maxvanbakel not a problem, glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

For an endless animation loop, you could use this:

```
function animate() { 
  $("#start").animate({opacity: .3}, "slow", 
    function () {
      $("#start").animate({height: 0}, "fast", animate);
    }
  );
}

$(".button").click(animate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) function. Anyway your code works fine:

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/nbnV6/1/